# 'None,\n `date` RE' SQL; ProgrammingError(1064, u

Tags: mysql

I just want to ask you how to fix this SQL Query bug. I already used google and used the column 'real' like they said it on stackoverflow but it still doesnt work for me :/

```
        execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reportrunrecords (report_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                                                                 player_id INTEGER REFERENCES players ON DELETE CASCADE,
                                                                 report_player_id INTEGER REFERENCES players ON DELETE CASCADE,
                                                                 recordID INTEGER,
                                                                 run_id INTEGER,
                                                                 map_id INTEGER,
                                                                 reason INTEGER DEFAULT None,
                                                                 `date` REAL,
                                                                 status INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
                                                                 status_date REAL DEFAULT 0,
                                                                 status_player_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0
                                                                 )""")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for an integer cannot be "None". The error you are receiving is due to a syntax error for using an unrecognizable keyword. I also doubt you want a column called `date` to be of `REAL` (a numeric type).

I'm thinking you'd like an INTEGER type column where NULLs are allowed, and a `date` column that holds actual dates:

```
...
reason INTEGER NULL,
`date` DATETIME,
...
```